# Auto layout unsatisfiable constraints

Tags: ios, ipad, constraints, autolayout, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to layout a colored swatch (just a `UIView` with its background color set) such that it is on the left of its container view. It is of fixed width (`10`) and fixed distance (`8`) from the left, top, and bottom of its container. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The swatch is the grey thing. Other content will of course appear to the right, but I'm not even at that point yet.

Here are the constraints I have applied to the swatch:

[image]

However, at runtime I get unsatisfiable constraints:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15e53fe0 V:[UIView:0x15e57250]-(8)-|   (Names: '|':LogEntryView:0x15e57740 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x15e54010 V:|-(8)-[UIView:0x15e57250]   (Names: '|':LogEntryView:0x15e57740 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x15e528c0 h=-&- v=-&- LogEntryView:0x15e57740.height == LogEntryView:0x15e57150.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x15e54f80 h=--& v=--& V:[LogEntryView:0x15e57150(0)]>"
)
```

Having done some reading, I suspect it's the `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`s that are the problem. However, I cannot work out why they're being added. I've checked every view to ensure `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is `NO`, and it is. I used Interface Builder, and that is supposed to do so automatically anyway.

If I remove both my vertical constraints then the error does not display. If I remove only one of my vertical constraints (top or bottom, doesn't matter) then the error does not display.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

**UPDATE:** I realized I had the following in my `LogEntryView` code (I'm using Xamarin):

```
    public LogEntryView()
    {
        var arr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("LogEntryView", this, null);
        var v = (UIView)Runtime.GetNSObject(arr.ValueAt(0));
        v.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, Frame.Width, Frame.Height);
        this.AddSubview(v);
    }
```

Checking `v.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` directly after loading it from the NIB showed that it was `true`. I don't understand why, since I thought the NIB would store it as false as shown in interface builder. I changed this code to:

```
    public LogEntryView()
    {
        this.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        var arr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("LogEntryView", this, null);
        var v = (UIView)Runtime.GetNSObject(arr.ValueAt(0));
        v.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        this.AddSubview(v);
    }
```

Now the error doesn't appear, but I have a different problem: the swatch doesn't appear at all now. Any ideas?

Comment: Everything looks perfect in IB, even when I resize the view or execute Update Frames/Constraints.

Comment: Yep, I've been all the way up the stack: `LogEntryView`, `LogEntryCell` (it's hosted in a collection view), and the view that has the collection view in it (which is a root view). They all have `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`. This is doing my head in.

Comment: I think you are better to mark this question as solved (move update to the answer) and create a new one.